# Geoserver URL rewrite is not working in IIS

Tags: geoserver, iis

I have a website which is running on default port 80 in IIS and it's `https`, and also in the same server , a `geoserver` instance is running on `port 8080`.

I need to redirect all the geoserver requests from my website to geoserver(8080) . I wrote a URL rewrite in IIS , but its not working ,

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="geoserver">
                    <match url="^geoserver/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/{R:1}" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

And in geoserver global configuration ,I've put proxy base url as following ,

```
https://mydomain.com/geoserver/
```

Comment: It's fixed when add the same rule as global rule . Means to the root of the all application in the IIS